# Keep "[" and "]" marks when I save vim?

Tags: vim

When I save with `:w`, `[` and `]` marks disappears. How can I keep these marks?

Answer (score 3):

This command-line mode mapping replaces `w` with `lockmarks w` when `w` is the first character being typed in the `:` command-line:

```
cnoremap <expr> w getcmdtype() == ':' ? (getcmdpos() == 1 ? 'lockmarks w' : 'w') : 'w'
```

See `:help map-<expr>`, `:help getcmdtype()`, `:help getcmdpos()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `:lockmarks w`.

Show more `:h :lockmarks`.